# Redirect all file reading and writing

Tags: windows, redirect, file-io

I'm using a virtual file system (PhysFS) in my application. Is there any way to redirect all file reading and writing through this virtual file system? I would like everything to be redirected, such that even third-party libraries go through this file system.

Is there something similar to `rdbuf`, but for *all* file IO, both though C++ streams and the old C `FILE` objects?

---

**Edit:** *OS dependent*

The platform I'm currently interested in is Windows, so I'd like to know how this can be don with the WinAPI. Also, is file redirection a common feature of OSes?

Comment: You should really ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only through an operating-system specific API, you might be able to.